# Single list item with multiple anchors

Tags: html, accessibility, html-lists, anchor

Is it accessible to have multiple links in a single list item ?

Let say I need to have code like this one below:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">link 1</a> <a href="#">link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link 3</a> <a href="#">link 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link 5</a> <a href="#">link 6</a></li>
</ul>
```

Going thru the list with a `tab` key, VoiceOver reads that there are a 3 items list (which is true). But going thru the whole list I need to use the `tab` key 6 times because in every single `<li>` there are two `anchors`.

Is it still accessible for the visually impaired people if they hear that there is a list with 3 items, but going thru the list they find out that actually there are six `anchors`?

Will that be confusing or inserting two anchors inside one `<li>` is fine?

***EDITED***:

[image]

This is how should it look. And this is why I inserted two `anchors` inside single `<li>`

The thing is links on the left are of different lengths and on the right the same (let's say it's an "only icon link").

The only thing that comes to my mind is to style it like in this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/n0azsq75/

But I would like to have the links to the left and right touch hug together

Comment: The key question is **why are you doing this**, it could be fine or it could be that a different element / structure is more appropriate. What is the reason to have two anchors within a `<li>`? (it is valid HTML FYI, this would just be optimising accessibility / semantic meaning as you pointed out, 3 items but 6 links is a bit confusing to screen readers)

Comment: It's a particular UI use case (and specific styling), this is why the HTML looks like this

Comment: So is it for layout rather than anything else (or are the two links directly related to each other?)? As if that is the case we could just manipulate the CSS to create the design and have better / more semantic HTML.

Comment: I manipulated a little bit with CSS, the design is a bit different, I will see if the client agrees with that. Thanks for confirming the doubts about a11y.

Comment: It might be helpful if you could provide some example content in there to illustrate how the links within a given `<li/>` relate to one another?

Comment: @AlexanderNied I edited the question

Comment: @MarcinMroczko - thanks, but I meant more like clarifying with example content that matched your use case.  I'm trying to understand if the two links in the `<li/>` relate to each other, and how the `<li/>` items relate to one another.  Like some dummy content that approximates your actual content, or a description of the items...

Answer (score 2):

A list item can have pretty much have any HTML inside it so you could potentially have lots and lots of interactive elements and thus lots of tab stops within a list item.  There isn't a(n) (accessibility) problem with that.

What might be a problem is the **purpose** of using a list.  If you are truly grouping things into enumerated chunks of information, then a list is exactly what you want to use (whether an ordered or unordered list).  But if you are using a list to get a certain layout, as in your jsfiddle example, but are not really chunking information together, then you'd want to remove the semantics of the list with [`role="presentation"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#presentation).

```
<ul role="presentation">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Or, alternatively, use `<div>` or `<span>` elements and use CSS to achieve the layout you desire.  My hunch is that [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) or [`grid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) would be sufficient, but if you truly need something that looks like a list that is not in fact actually a list you can leverage [`display: list-item`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display-listitem).

Comment: It's best not to change the semantics of a natively semantic element.

Comment: Yeah I think it's better to use `div` and `spans` instead of changing original semantics of the `ul`